# Erro ao dar insert no MySQL pelo python

Tags: mysql, python, sql, sql-insert

Tenho a tabela no meu banco:

```
create table tweets(
    ID_Tweet int not null auto_increment,
    ID_Candidato int not null,
    Conteudo_Tweet varchar(470) not null,
    constraint PK_tweets_ID primary key (ID_Tweet),
    constraint FK_tweets_IdCandidato foreign key (ID_Candidato) references candidatos (ID_Candidato)
);
```

No qual estou tentando armazenar o seguinte conteúdo:

> João Doria(@jdoriajr), em 31 de out de 2018, tweetou:
>
> "Pessoal, recebi há pouco a visita do Governador eleito pelo Rio
>   Grande do Sul, @EduardoLeite_. Fico feliz em ver um jovem tão
>   competente e preparado no comando de seu Estado. Agradeço a gentileza
>   da visita. São Paulo e Rio Grande do Sul vão acelerar juntos pelo
>   Brasil! #Acelera"
>
> Responder: 65 Retweetar: 129 Curtir: 1,6 mil

Para pular as linhas estou dando `\n` e também estou colocando `\` antes das aspas duplas.

Estou tentando inserir da seguinte forma:

```
    conexao = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', db='eleicoes', use_unicode = True, charset = 'utf8mb4', autocommit = True)
    cursorUrl = conexao.cursor()
    cursorUrl.execute(f'insert into tweets (ID_Candidato, Conteudo_Tweet) values ({1}, "{tweet}")') # tweet é a string com o conteúdo citado anteriormente
    cursorUrl.close()
    conexao.close()
```

No entando, sempre recebo o mesmo erro:

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Pessoal, recebi há pouco a visita do Governador eleito pelo Rio Grande do Sul, ' at line 3")

Quando tento incluir o mesmo conteúdo direto pelo MySQL Workbench, consigo sem problemas. Tudo me leva a crer que tem algo a ver com os caracteres especiais @ e _, mas não sei ao certo. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como é possível verificar pela mensagem de erro, mais especificamente em `near 'Pessoal, recebi`, o problema não é nos caracteres citados, mas sim  nas aspas do texto.

Neste link há um exemplo melhor de como fazer este tipo de insert: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12902951/1256062

```py
sql = "insert into tweets (ID_Candidato, Conteudo_Tweet) values (%s, %s)"
cursorUrl.execute(sql, (idCandidato, tweet))
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me estás a definir o valor do **ID_Candidato** incorretamente. Em vez de `{1}` não deverias ter algo do tipo `{id_candidato}`? Tipo assim:

```py
id_candidato = <ID do candidato aqui>
cursorUrl.execute(f'insert into tweets (ID_Candidato, Conteudo_Tweet) values ({id_candidato}, "{tweet}")')
```

Comment: Na prática é igual a eu colocar a variável, eu coloquei o número 1 fixo intencionalmente, pois estou me referindo a um candidato em específico.

Comment: Se queres te referir ao candidato de ID 1, não deves colocar as cavetas {}. Fica apenas assim `cursorUrl.execute(f'insert into tweets (ID_Candidato, Conteudo_Tweet) values (1, "{tweet}")')`